# How to find the ranking of a given leaderboard in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list,

```
[100,100,50,40,40,20,10]
```

The list above is the leaderboard scores of different people. I want to convert or find their ranks and store it in a list like this:

```
[1,1,2,3,3,4,5]
```

Is there are possible way of doing something like this in Python3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
scores = [100,100,50,40,40,20,10]
all_scores = sorted(set(scores), reverse=True)

ranks = [all_scores.index(x) + 1 for x in scores]

print(ranks)
```

This prints:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```

The way this works is we take the unique elements from the list of scores (`set(scores)`) and sort them in descending order. Then, we find the position of each element in `scores` within that list, and add 1 to get the 1-based ranks rather than 0-based.

Answer (score 1):

If there are two winners (e.g. rank:1), the follower should be ranked 3rd. Regarding this approach, this should do the work:

```
>>> grades = [100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10] 
>>> ranks = [grades.index(x)+1 for x in sorted(grades, reverse=True)]
>>> ranks
[1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pandas.series`

```
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(scores)
result = series.rank(method="dense", ascending=0).astype(int).values.tolist()
```

output:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5]
```